# How to Have Child Links Displayed after being Visited after Display:none, Display: Hover

Tags: css, list, parent-child, nav, display

I have a Child Links Nav Menu that only displays if the parent is hovered over. so I used Display: None, and then a:Hover Display, What I would like to have is that once one of the Child Links is visited (Clicked On) that the Child Links Menu then is Displayed.

I have a fiddle here, make sure to minimize the html screen so that the nav menu doesnt flicker.

https://jsfiddle.net/omq2ky0v/

```
        html {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
      background-color: #efe;
    }

    a:link,
    a:visited {
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    /* Standard Nav Menu */
    .site-nav ul {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .site-nav ul:before, .site-nav ul:after { content: ""; display: table; }
    .site-nav ul:after { clear: both; }
    .site-nav ul { *zoom: 1; }

    .site-nav ul li {
        list-style: none;
        display: inline-block;
    }


    .site-nav ul li a:link,
    .site-nav ul li a:visited {
        display: block;
    }


    /* Clearfix */
    .clearfix:before, .clearfix:after { content: ""; display: table; }
    .clearfix:after { clear: both; }
    .clearfix { *zoom: 1; }

    /* Children Links */

    .page_item_has_children:hover .children { 
    display: block;}

    .page-item:hover {text-decoration: none;}
    .children {
        display: none;
    }


    .children-links {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        font-size: 80%;
    }

    .children-links a:link,
    .children-links a:visited {
        text-decoration: none;
        padding-bottom: 2px;
    }

    .children-links ul {
        float: left;
    }

    .children-links li {
        margin-right: 20px;
    }

    .children-links .parent-link {
        float: left;
        margin-right: 20px;
        padding-right: 20px;
        border-right: 1px solid #DDD;
        font-size: 120%;
```

Answer (score 1):

Give the parent on click an class `active` and via css permanent show the childs if the parent have that class:

```
.page_item.active > .children > .page_item{
    display: block;
}
```

if you click somewhere else in the body, remove the class `active` from the parent, to let the childs disapear:

```
$('document').on('mousedown', function(oEvent){
    // check if navigation is open and if one of the childs is clicked, and do stuff
    $(oEvent.currentTarget) ....
});
```

Comment: where would I put that second block?

Comment: its Javascript code - you have to put it in a script tag in your header (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_script.asp). it is not complete (needs to check if current target is in tree of your active navigation, if yes, do nothing / handle click on your navigation - like show / hide nav elements. if no, check if there is an active navigation and remove the `active` class)

Comment: instead of a global listener, you can also use "mouseleave", which will covers the childelements.


$('document').on('mouseleave', '.page_item.active', function(){
    $(this).closest('.page_item.active').removeClass('active');
})

Comment: Thanks for your input, well Im curious about Javascript but for the time being Marks solution was adequate. I don't foresee that his answer could cause problems in the future. Do you?

Comment: seems i have missunderstood your request, marks answer is the correct one

Answer (score 0):

u can try this

> .current_page_ancestor a:visited + ul.children{   display:block
>   !important; }

i have also tried this in jsFiddle in your previous codes.

`enter code here`https://jsfiddle.net/omq2ky0v/8/

Comment: Great! That Works. Thank you

Comment: doesnt this force a `display: block` even after a reload of the page?
couse the visited flag is saved by the browser for visted ankers.

Comment: that's what actually what he said he needs. Display it if its visited?

Comment: ok, thought it should disapear after a reload. then its fine :)

Comment: what problem i think in this is that is still force the **children** to display even if the parent link was not yet  visited. but im finding solutions to it right currently. ;)

Comment: Yes thats right, Display if its visited. One more question if you don't mind. Now that the child nav menu is being displayed how can I give the current or active page styling to differentiate it from the other choices?

By the way im still a new member so I voted your solution up, but will have to earn some reputation myself before anything shows.

Comment: if your using different files for different pages. you can add some class like `.active` in the for the current page and just call it in **css** to add some designs.